# How can I acces the value of email from this firebase returned result?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I am using ionic2 and firebase. Using the Angularfire2, I am retrieving a user by the codes below: if I try  something like this:

```
console.log(user.email);
```

I get undefined

```
signup_with_username(email: string, password: string) {

    this.email = email;

    const user_from_db = this.afDb.list('/users', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'email',
            equalTo: this.email,
            limitTo: 1,
        }
    });

    user_from_db.subscribe(user => console.log(user));

}
```

[image]

Comment: try with user[0] or user[0].email

Comment: that worked! thxxx! but is this reliable? or is there a better way ?

Comment: yes its it....and more over its depends on the structure of the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the below

```
user_from_db.subscribe(user => console.log(user));
```

with

```
user_from_db.subscribe(user => console.log(user[0].email));
```